Convergence of p_ji (k) in irreducible, aperiodic finite Markov chains
Image for the question
Hello, I can't prove the blue step? Can someone see how? It is known:  All terms are =>0, m_ii=Sum k=1 to inf kf_ii, f_ji=sum k=1 to inf f_ji (k)=<1 . Sum i=1 to N of p_ji(k) =1 for all k. Thank you in advance.
